# How do you integrate $(1 + \cos(x))^{5/2} dx$?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I tried substituting $\cos(x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x/2)$ but still can't figure it out. Is there any other identity to help with this integration?

Comment: $1+\cos x=2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can use $\cos(x)=2\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})-1$ the next step can be to use $\cos^5(\frac{x}{2})=\cos(\frac{x}{2})(1-\sin^4(\frac{x}{2}))$

Comment: Just remember about the absolute value: $\big(\cos^2\frac{x}{2}\big)^\frac52 = |\cos \frac{x}{2}|^5$

Comment: Okay. Just a query does it matter in an indefinite integral.

Comment: Yes it does; If you want to write the formula for the indefinite integral on the domain $D=\mathbb{R}$, that means that for some $x$ its derivative is supposed to be $(\cos \frac{x}{2})^5$ and for some other it is supposed to be $-(\cos \frac{x}{2})^5$. If you neglect the absolute value, you won't get that result.

Comment: Thanks for answering.